# Kafka clean startup: WARN ... leader replied with an unknown offset

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to get a *clean* startup of a Kafka cluster within docker, using the Confluent Kafka 5.0.0 distribution.

Alas, I get warnings

> experimental_broker-1    | [2018-10-16 08:30:25,486] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Based on follower's leader epoch, leader replied with an unknown offset in MyNewlyCreatedTopic-0. The initial fetch offset 0 will be used for truncation. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

which I am trying to understand / get rid of.

Context:

- single zookeeper
- three Kafka brokers
- initialization script which creates MyNewlyCreatedTopic through zookeeper / kafka-topics, after all brokers have come up

All of this happens on a `docker-compose up`; create more topics, get more warnings.

Is this normal? What can I do to get rid of these warnings?

In a way, using the "initial" fetch offset is quite correct (this is a totally fresh set of containers, after all), but why is that a warning?

Comment: If you're not persisting the Kafka data, it should always start clean

Comment: I kill using `docker-compose down -v` - not that I would have any volumes in that experimental stack. So I expect `docker-compose up` to yield a totally fresh and clean environment - and still I get WARN in the log, even without any application (consumer, producer) around. Would the docker-compose.yml help?

Comment: If you have no volumes, then as I said, it should be clean. I'm not particularly sure why you would be seeing any warnings, but the message looks like it's just initializing the offset to 0, and is not necessarily something to be concerned with on a fresh boot